# Package dependencies based on condition [debian]

Tags: build, debian, ubuntu-12.04, packaging

For debian packages, Is that possible to have Depends name generated during install time based on some condition? For example,

For package PACKAGE-1, based on the kernel version it can depend on PACKAGE-A or PACKAGE-B... I cant hardcode depends package name during build time because its decided based on the system (kernel version) on its getting installed...such as
Depends: PACKAGE-A [`uname -r` >= '3.13.0-40'], PACKAGE-B [`uname -r` < '3.13.0-40']

FYI
Seems such dependencies can be created based on arch but couldn't any get if it can be customized further...
Depends: foo [i386], bar [amd64]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct- what you are asking for is not possible with current dpkg/apt.

Unless this is for a kernel module, the right thing to do is probably to ship the binaries for both `PACKAGE-A` and `PACKAGE-B` in the same deb, and include a script that chooses between them at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! I did the same.